# Conditional formatting based on another cell's text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheets table of names and statistics that go along with said names. I'm trying to use a dropdown menu on a specific cell so that when I select a specific name from the dropdown, all of the cells that start with the same name will be highlighted.

Comment: This is straightforward "conditional formatting". Review [this information](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dropdown is in B2. Please select entire sheet and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... *Custom formula is* and:

```
=regexmatch(A1,"^"&$B$2)
```

with highlighting of your choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Since for `all of the cells that start with the same name` this could be slow.

Answer (score 0):

### custom formula: **`=IF(I1=H$4, 1)`**

[image: 0]